# Установка необходимого из requirements.txt на мак

Tags: django, pip

всем привет! у меня проект на джанго-питон. Но чтоб его запустить на мак нужно установить все ннеобходимое из requirements.txt но похоже кто писал requirements писал его под windows . Вопрос каким образом можно все установить на macox. Вот к примеру скачиваю зип папку а дальше что делать?? как установить из этой зип папки на мак?

Comment: Абсолютно такой же `pip install -r requirements.txt` как и в винде, не? Желательно внутри virtualenv

Comment: да , но при запуске выдает ошибку 1) MacBook-Pro:untitled11 User$ cd ~/Desktop/roadBasket/
(untitled11) MacBook-Pro:roadBasket User$ Pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting Django==1.11.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django==1.11.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )

Comment: Похоже, у вас питон слишком старый и его нужно обновить